# How to get rid of values from Numpy array without loop?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array similar to the following that represents neighbors of each individual (This is first generated by igraph package then converted to numpy array

```
import numpy as np
import igraph
Edges = 2
NumNodes = 30
DisGraph = igraph.GraphBase.Barabasi(NumNodes, Edges)
Neighbors = map(DisGraph.neighbors, range(NumNodes))
Neighbors = np.asarray(DisNeighbors)
```

):

```
Neighbors=[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11, 23, 24, 27]
 [0, 2, 3, 4, 9, 10, 13, 16, 17, 19, 25, 27] [0, 1, 10, 22]
 [0, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 12, 14, 15, 21, 22] [0, 1]
 [0, 3, 7, 11, 15, 23, 24, 25, 29] [0, 3] [3, 5, 18] [0, 3, 12, 16, 18]
 [0, 1, 13] [1, 2, 14, 20] [0, 5] [3, 8, 19] [1, 9, 21, 28]
 [3, 10, 17, 20, 26] [3, 5] [1, 8] [1, 14, 26] [7, 8] [1, 12] [10, 14, 28]
 [3, 13] [2, 3] [0, 5] [0, 5] [1, 5] [14, 17] [0, 1, 29] [13, 20] [5, 27]]
```

I would like to find a way to get ride of certain numbers from this array,
possibly without using loop.
For example, if I have a list:

```
List = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]
```

Then, I would like the resulting Neighbors array to have these values in List removed.

Any help will be appreciated.

Current answer that I have is the following:

```
for aa in List:
    i=0
    for bb in Neighbors:
        Neighbors[i] = [cc for cc in bb if cc != aa]
        i=i+1
```

But I would like to know if there are more efficient way of handling this, as I am working with arrays sizing millions.

Comment: That's not a numpy array. The dimensions don't match up. In a (2-d) array, each row has to have the same number of elements.

Comment: print(type(Neighbors)) gives <type 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could post a short, **working** piece of code that generates `Neighbors`. Currently it's not clear what kind of input you're actually getting or what kind of output you want. And the code you have above isn't valid Python code. See [this help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I am not sure if you are familiar with igraph package.  I use igraph package to create graph of several million nodes then use .neighbor function to extract neighbors of each and every node. Then I convert to numpy array by using numpy.asarray so that I can manipulate it.. which I am having lots of trouble with. any suggestions?

Comment: This sounds nothing like your original post, so now I am really confused.  Are you having problems with numpy.asarray, or are you having problems removing elements from your array?

Comment: I am having problems removing elements from Neighbors array, which is not in stardard numpy (2-d) array format like you describe in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by "have these values in List removed" (what do you mean, "remove"?).  Generally, though, you can select points within an array via:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.random_integers(0,10,[10,10])
b = np.random.random_integers(0,10,5)

for r in b:
    a[a==r] = -999


a
Out[12]: 
array([[   5,    1, -999,    3,    7,    5,    8,    3,    8,    4],
       [   8,    8, -999,    7, -999,    8, -999, -999,    4,    7],
       [  10, -999, -999, -999, -999,    1, -999,    7,   10, -999],
       [   3,   10,    8, -999,    8,    4, -999,    7,    4,    3],
       [   4, -999,    4, -999, -999, -999, -999, -999, -999, -999],
       [   5,    3, -999,   10,   10, -999,   10,   10,    3,    8],
       [   8,    5, -999, -999,    7, -999,    1,    8, -999,    8],
       [   4,    3,    8, -999,    3,    5,    4, -999,    4,   10],
       [   4,    3,    7,    4, -999,    7,    7,    7, -999,    8],
       [-999,   10, -999,    5,    1,    5,    1,   10,    5,    1]])
```